# how to use strip() in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, strip

I have a text file `test.txt` which has in it `'a 2hello 3fox 2hen 1dog'`.
I want to read the file and then add all the items into a list, then `strip` the integers so it will result in the list looking like this `'a hello fox hen dog'`

I tried this but my code is not working. The result is `['a 2hello 3foz 2hen 1dog']`. thanks

```
newList = [] 
filename = input("Enter a file to read: ") 
openfile = open(filename,'r')

for word in openfile:
    newList.append(word)



for item in newList:
    item.strip("1")
    item.strip("2")
    item.strip("3")

print(newList)
openfile.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

from [python Doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html)

> str.strip([chars])
> Return a copy of the string with the leading and
>   trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying
>   the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars
>   argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a
>   prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

Strip wont modify the string, returns a copy of the string after removing the characters mentioned.

```
>>> text = '132abcd13232111'
>>> text.strip('123')
'abcd'
>>> text
'132abcd13232111'
```

You can try:

```
out_put = []
for item in newList:
    out_put.append(item.strip("123"))
```

If you want to remove all `123` then use regular expression `re.sub`

```
import re
newList = [re.sub('[123]', '', word) for word in openfile]
```

**Note:** This will remove all `123` from the each line

Comment: your first example will not work with provided input

Answer (score 3):

Pointers:

- `strip` returns a *new* string, so you need to assign that to something. (better yet, just use a list comprehension)
- Iterating over a file object gives you *lines*, not words;
- so instead you can `read` the whole thing then `split` on spaces.
- The `with` statement saves you from having to call `close` manually.
- `strip` accepts multiple characters, so you don't need to call it three times.

Code:

```
filename = input("Enter a file to read: ") 
with open(filename, 'r') as openfile:
    new_list = [word.strip('123') for word in openfile.read().split()]
print(new_list)
```

This will give you a list that looks like `['a', 'hello', 'fox', 'hen', 'dog']`
If you want to turn it back into a string, you can use `' '.join(new_list)`

Answer (score 2):

there are several types of strips in python, basically they strip some specified char in every line. In your case you could use `lstrip` or just `strip`:

```
s = 'a 2hello 3fox 2hen 1dog'
' '.join([word.strip('0123456789') for word in s.split()])
```

Output:

```
'a hello fox hen dog'
```

Answer (score 2):

A function in Python is called in this way:

```
result = function(arguments...)
```

This calls `function` with the arguments and stores the result in `result`.

If you discard the function call result as you do in your case, it will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use it is:

```
l=[]
for x in range(5):  
   l.append("something")
l.strip()
```

This will remove all spaces